# Help on content management integration

Tags: php, content-management-system

I was wondering if I could implement a content management system for the site I am designing. I don't want something front end like joomla, as i've designed and coded the site myself.

To illustrate what I want my website is; www.nclgolf.co.uk
user: admin
pass: shank123

I want a very basic CMS to store and call articles in the News and Latest Updates section of the site, basically nesting the CMS in that div. I was wondering if it was possible? The closest thing i've found searching here on CMS which may do the job is N2.

Any suggestions? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I actually developed a CMS that is very similar to what you are looking for. I've used WordPress and Joomla for the majority of the sites I've done, but I found them a bit too bulky for my liking, so I put together a CMS called "Inline Content Management" that is a simple PHP script that you can install on your site and with jQuery front end, it allows you to define editable Divs and users who are allowed to edit these divs.

The link to the component:

http://www.binpress.com/app/inline-content-management/471?ad=1229

A more in depth description on my personal website (ironically, this website uses WordPress):

http://www.travisweston.com/portfolio/inline-content-management/